# How to prevent or remove library string resources from ending in my apk?

Tags: android, apk, android-resources, android-library, android-build

I use an external library which declares some strings, these end up in my apk and I need to remove them or prevent them to getting there in the first place.

I've look around for a solution but I only find how to remove unused resources and this does not fix it.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: I've tried excluding them on gradle/implementation and been searching for a solution all over the net :\